# Get cursor position, accounting for tabs

Tags: vim

In my vim plugin I obtain the current cursor position using Ruby's `w.cursor`.

The column number it gives me is based on the tabsize of 1. E.g. if the current line is `\t\tfoo`, and the cursor is placed at `f`, its position will be reported as 3.

What I need is the cursor position based on the tabsize of 8 (because that's what the Haskell standard specifies). So, in the example above, I need the column number of `f` to be 17, independent of the `ts` setting.

How do I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attention! In Vim parlance, *column* refers to the byte index. A `<Tab>` character is represented by a single (0x09) byte, that's giving you the 1. Non-ASCII characters (such as umlauts or Kanji) will "occupy" 2, 3, or more (depending on the encoding) columns, but are visually represented by a single / double cell.

Apparently, you're interested in the screen width (where a `<Tab>` can occupy between 1..8 cells), which Vim's documentation refers to as *virtual column*, and can be accessed through functions like `virtcol()`, and the recent `strdisplaywidth()`.

Comment: IIUC, to get what I want (position based on `ts=8`), I'll need to set and then reset `ts`. I'm worried that this may result in screen flickering, because vim reformats the code when I change `ts`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: No! Ruby's `w.cursor[1]` corresponds to `col('.')` in Vimscript. You need to use `virtcol('.')` instead.

Comment: Yes, I realize that `virtcol` is much closer to what I need than `w.cursor` or `col`. My problem is that the `virtcol`'s result depends on the `ts` setting. I need the result computed for `ts=8` independent of whatever the user really set `ts` to. But changing it will lead to flickering.

Comment: You have strange requirements; to avoid the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you'd better state your final goal in your question.

Comment: It's either changing `ts`, or grabbing the text up to the cursor (with `col('.')` and `strpart()`), and calculating the width yourself.

Comment: My plugin works with Haskell code. By [definition](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3), in Haskell the tab is equivalent to 8 spaces, and various external tools (with which my plugin interacts) treat them as 8 characters. At the same time, the user may want to display tabs as a different number of spaces, which is completely irrelevant for the purpose of my plugin. Yes, it's a mess, and tabs are discouraged in Haskell, but as a plugin writer I want my plugin to work correctly even in such cases.

Comment: I ended up temporarily changing `ts`. Turns out that doesn't lead to screen flickering, because the screen is not refreshed before the command is finished. I also wrote down some details here: http://ro-che.info/articles/2013-12-14-vim-positions.html

Comment: Yeah, as long as you do this in one function, Vim doesn't update the screen yet. And great article!